# is RCS permission in Android still signature level in 2020 ? (samsung/google)

Tags: android, permissions, signature, rich-communications-services

I'm trying read text message from Android RCS Message Apps (Google / Samsung)
What I was trying

- set permission concerned with rcs

  - `com.samsung.rcs.im.READ_PERMISSION` (samsung galaxy series)
  - `com.gsma.rcs.permission.RCS` (google)

But, I got this exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.internal.tapi.service.provider.HistoryLogProvider from ProcessRecord{e7c133 3845:com.gilapps.rcstest/u0a240} (pid=3845, uid=10240) requires com.gsma.services.permission.RCS or com.sec.imsservice.WRITE_IMS_PERMISSION
```

I'm guessing that maybe permission with RCS is still signature level permission.
Am I Right?

Comment: Hey, any news on this topic? I'm also struggling with this.

Comment: @Jerry Unfortunately, We're also stuck at that time. We can't find any answer about issue. So Sad.

Comment: What content URI do you use?